# What will be the effect of nitrogen if it filled in two wheelers tube?

Tags: tire, innertube

What if I fill liquid nitrogen in tube of two wheeler?? Is it OK?

Comment: It'd be ok, but would give no benefit at all.

Comment: it would destroy the tube at that temperature

Comment: @Trengot No, it wouldn't be OK. The qn says *liquid* nitrogen!

Comment: @andy256 True, I missed the liquid part. I'd be impressed if you could even do that.

Comment: @Trengot Yes, me too!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's just too darn dangerous!

Answer (score 4):

Liquid Nitrogen boils at -196 Degrees Celsius  (321 degrees Fahrenheit) and is cold enough that rubber will become brittle. Its probably not a good idea as I am fairly sure the the brittle rubber tube will not hold the pressure created as the liquid Nitrogen boils.

[View before you do it.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ciS6RLSECw4) and if you decide to go ahead, ring the emergency room before hand and book yourself a bed.

If you mean filling tires with pure nitrogen gas, refer [This question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/18688/what-are-the-advantages-of-filling-tires-with-nitrogen-instead-of-air)

Answer (score 0):

You are 78% of the way there already.

Air is 78% nitrogen, 20% oxygen, 2% other gases.

Therefore, the difference gained in using pure nitrogen is going to be minimal.
And accurately gauging air pressure will be tricky.